# Como acessar o gameObject, do Raycast do controle Gear VR?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity-5

Quero saber como posso ativar o laser vermelho do Gear VR e como posso saber informações do que o laser esta tocando ?

Comment: Qual laser? É algum emissor do próprio equipamento? Se sim, você já viu a documentação? O SDK para a Unity (que você provavelmente já está usando) não tem nada? Forneça um pouco mais de detalhes, se não fica difícil alguém conseguir te ajudar.

Comment: Seria o raycast do controle, se tinha alguma nativo com o sdk da oculus.

Comment: No SDK da Oculus não tem uma opção pra essa ativação? Edite a pergunta e forneça mais detalhes, pra aumentar as chances de que alguém possa te ajudar. :)

Comment: Geralmente existem SDKs que te dão tudo pronto, mas caso não tenha essa funcionalidade você vai ter que criar um raycast a partir do controle para frente ou filiar um gameObject vazio com o eixo z apontado para onde você quer e nele fazer o raycast para frente, pode chamar no update mesmo, e pra saber o que está tocando pode usar o hit.transform.gameObject, nesse caso o hit é o que o Physics.RayCast vai retornar (um RaycastHit). O raycast não é visível, vc vai ter que desenhar uma linha, usando o mesmo ponto e direção do raycast, e o tamanho dela vai ser a diferença do ponto inicial e do hit